# Error compiling simple C program using Cygwin, cmd and Sublime Text 2

Tags: c, build, cmd, cygwin, sublimetext2

I installed Cygwin in Windows 7. Then I set the environment variable to path, "C:\cygwin\bin", but when i try to *build* a simple "helloworld.c" file, it displays the following:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'C:\\programs\\helloworld.c', u'-o', u'C:\\programs/helloworld']]
[dir:  C:\programs]
[path: C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\TC\BIN]
[Finished]
```

and the code i wrote is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: cygwin uses /cygdrive as an alternate means of specifying a drive in a filename...  For example: /cygdrive/c/programs/helloworld.c for your program.  OR, if the file is within the cygwin installation tree, then you can specify it relative to cygwin's installation location as root.

Comment: Do you have gcc/g++ installed?

Comment: ok... i think i missed selecting the packages during installation ..... now can someone please guide me how to uninstall Cygwin?

Comment: You don't need to un-install it... Just re-run the setup program you originally ran (setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe)... when you get to the software selection screen, select gcc... they will be added to your installation.

Comment: Thanks man... did what you said... will update on this post soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install all the devel packages because you will need some of them in the near future.

To this end use setup-x86.exe (or setup-x86_64.exe on 64bits system) because it's the way of installing packages through Cygwin. If you don't have that executable, download it again (it's the one used to install Cygwin).

Remember using the correct format because in the cmd line at the end you wrote /helloworld instead of \helloword.